# On windows 10 machine bootloader is on wrong drive

Tags: windows, boot, ssd, windows-10, bootloader

I have SSD with OS and HDD with files, but loading starts from HDD which i want to replace,but when i unplug it system wont boot(EFI console opens). I didnt do anything, installer did it automatically. I use bitlocker on all devices and fast boot, UEFI. Did installer did that on purpose or by mistake? How should i fix it, so system boot from SSD?

Comment: The boot partition (and thus manager) always end up on the first viable drive.

Comment: Can you help to fix it? I need to remove the drive where windows installed a boot manager to

Comment: First, you need to determine how your system boots (BIOS or UEFI) and update your question with that information. With Windows, the easiest way would be to look at the partition schema of the boot drive (the HDD): GPT means UEFI, MBR means BIOS.

Comment: its uefi with gpt table

Answer (score 1):

Windows Setup likes touching random unrelated disks inexplicably. Disconnect all disks except the one you want it to use then install Windows.